# restrict some customers from buying products based on zip codes

Tags: shipping-methods

we are using  customized shipping method something like "flat rate" shipping method.

we have to restrict the customer from buying products from some zip codes.

how we can achieve this?

Comment: do you mean you want to disable flat rate shipping method for some zipcodes ?

Comment: no, i integrated one more shipping method as similar to "flat rate".

we are using only that shipping method in our site.

if we use table rate shipping methiod , we can restrict "zip codes"

but we are using customized shipping method as like "flat rate", i have to restrict the zip codes for that shipping method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shipping method carrier module you should have the method `collectRates`.

You can make it look like this:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $postCode = $request->setDestPostcode();
    $restrictedCodes = array(....); //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
    if (in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
         return false;
    }
    //rest of your method here
}
```

Comment: i will try @Marius......

Comment: sorry for delay, there was no internet, is this right = > http://pastebin.com/gPXwRMn1 because i gave "1" in restricted codes, 

now its not supporting any zip codes

Comment: if i give  = > array(1, 2)  = > than its not allowing for any zip codes.

if i give  = > array(11, 22)  = > than its allowing for all zip codes.

means if i give single digit means its not  allowing for all zip codes, but if i give more than single digit,

than its allowing for all zip....

Comment: Theoretically this should not happen. Try to debug the line and see the value of `$postCode`

Comment: i am really not getting what to do.....

Comment: please check what else i can do to solve this....

Comment: Sorry. I have no other ideas. I've written what I thought it could be a solution. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: that's fine Marius , you gave me the hint, its almost working, i will try from now, thanks a lot......

Answer (score 1):

You can try my recently created extension

app\etc\modules\Sipping_Disable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sipping_Disable>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Sipping_Disable>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Sipping\Disable\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sipping_Disable>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Sipping_Disable>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <disable>
        <class>Sipping_Disable_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>disable_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </disable>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping>Sipping_Disable_Model_Shipping_Shipping</shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Sipping\Disable\Model\Shipping\Shipping.php

```
<?php
class Sipping_Disable_Model_Shipping_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)) {
           return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $carrierCode
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)
    {
          $regionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode();
            $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $ZipCodes = array('12345','54454'); //all zip codes put here where you want disable shipping
            $shippingAddress = $cart->getShippingAddress();
            $zip = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
           switch ($carrierCode) {
                case 'youshippingCode': // put your shipping code
                if (in_array($zip ,$ZipCodes)) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;

      }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, i  will try this ..... can you give me an option for all zip codes to put where we can enable shipping

Comment: you want to manage disable zip's code from admin ?

Comment: means what zip code i enter in Shipping.php, those zip codes only should allow customer to buy the products

Comment: where you want to disable shipping

Comment: in checkout page, once he enter the zip code in shipping information.....

Comment: Please put those zipcodes in  $ZipCodes = array('12345','54454'); where you want to restrict the customer from buying products

Comment: cache is disabled .

is there anything i need to do from admin panel side, because its not working for me

Comment: Make sure that you have to put right shipping code here :case 'youshippingCode': // put your shipping code

Comment: is there any way i can get the shipping method code ?

Comment: Mage::lof($carrierCode,null,'careercode.log'); put this code befor  $regionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode(); this line and make an order then see it in var/log/careercode.log file

Comment: i got the shipping method code by here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84418/how-to-find-the-shipping-method-code-in-magento?noredirect=1#comment110953_84418

, now i am checking....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29607/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-arunendra).