# how to find the shipping method code in magento

Tags: shipping-methods

As we have shipping method code for each shipping method.

I want to know how to find that shipping method code

Comment: Do you want the list of all shipping method codes ? Or do you want to get the shipping method of a particular object for instance an order ?

Comment: i want to get the list of all shipping method codes including customized shipping methods.....

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, how would you get the shipping method of a particular object? Like for tracking if i wanted to include it in an email or even display on a page the particular code they chose on checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as magento system,for a shipping method,it ***method code***  is ***define  in it's Shipping method class***.

In `cofig.xml`,magento define it `model class`.

**Example:** `<model>shipping/carrier_tablerate</model>`

On that model class,You can get method name from `$_code` variable

**Example: for table rate method:**

```
class Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{..

 protected $_code = 'tablerate'; // this method code:
..
```

Comment: mpperproductshipping

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function to retrieve all the shipping method codes (based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433627/programatically-retrieve-list-of-all-shipping-methods)

```
public function getAllShippingMethodsCode()
{
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();

    $options = array();

    foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier)
    {
        if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())
        {
            foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)
            {
                $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                $options[] = $_code;
            }
        }
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: please put this as command or descibe somehing

Comment: we bought one extension. this is our config.xml

http://pastebin.com/1D8baRJr

can you please check the code and inform me the shipping method code ?

Comment: Check this file: Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery that's where the code should be declared. Or paste the code if you want.

Answer (score 1):

even u can use SOAP webservice calls to see the Shipping method codes like this

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login('cats', 'sudhir123');
echo "\nSession Id = ";
var_dump($sessionId);
$cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, '3');
echo "\nCart Id = ";
var_dump($cartId);
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, $cartId);   
echo "\nAvailable Shipping methods = ";
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: i will try @Sudhir Belagali

Comment: we are doing android app for magento site, we are using catalog price rules to give discounts in site and we want to do the same in app. is there any android API , so that we can get the special price of the product in app

Comment: provision for giving discounts are available in SOAP magento webservice

Comment: can you please tell me the api name.....

Comment: s this is the link http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html and I am able to do most of the stuffs of magento website regarding Product details , customer details , adding to cart , shipping methods , and even discounts also

Comment: okay, i will search here....

Comment: I have used ksoap2 3rd party jar file for my android application and you can make use of my git hub link of my app https://github.com/sudhirbelagali/SnowDogSoapAndroid which uses magento soap api

Comment: @SudhirBelagali  I am new to API, i am try to display category tree using soap V2, my code : https://justpaste.it/7fv68, output : https://snag.gy/o2xbpA.jpg will u pls guide me what is my error?